# How to draw item with padding in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am drawing `Circle` and `Text` on `Canvas` in jetpack compose. I draw it without any problem through coordinate of `Canvas`. When I place the `circle` on `start` side of `Text` it too far away. It look like this way

[image]

I tried this piece of code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun CanvasView() {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val textToDraw = "Lab Return"
    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        color = Color.Black,
    )
    val textLayoutResult = remember(textToDraw) {
        textMeasurer.measure(textToDraw, style)
    }
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = textToDraw,
            style = style,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - textLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = center.y - textLayoutResult.size.height / 2,
            )
        )

        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Gray,
            radius = 6.dp.toPx(),
            center = Offset(center.x / 2, center.y)
        )
    }
}
```

I want `Circle` and `Text` with distance `15.dp`. Something like below image

[image]

Comment: have you tried to change the X coordinate here: center = Offset(center.x / 2, center.y)?
try this: center = Offset(center.x - textLayoutResult.size.width / 2 - with(LocalDensity.current) { 15.dp.toPx() }, center.y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the x coordinate of the Offset passed to drawCircle by subtracting the radius of the circle and the desired distance (which is as you described `15 dp`):

```
drawCircle(
    color = Color.Gray,
    radius = 6.dp.toPx(),
    center = Offset(
        center.x - textLayoutResult.size.width / 2 - 6.dp.toPx() - 15.dp.toPx(),
        center.y
    )
)
```